# CSS-align div elements from left to right

Tags: css, alignment

I have many divs in my php variable called $divs.

In html part i want to align this divs from left to right. How can i do this. Default setting aligns them up-down line and my page expand to bottom.

```
 <?php echo $divs ?>
```

**edit** in php section

```
$divs = //many divs in here
```

When i say `float: right;` it works but in html text in divs conflict with each other.text overflow from their divs. Thars my problem now.

Comment: Can you please post the output of the `$divs` variable?

Comment: please, add some html code, example of your div and layout

Comment: We need to see more code. But, what about: `#divContainer div { float: left; }`?

Answer (score 2):

```
<style>
.some-container-class>div {float:left;}
</style>

<div class="some-container-class">
 <?php echo $divs ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This is basically what I just wrote in my comment. Without further info/code, I think this is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

lets try this CSS code.. but it would be good if you atleast share the screenshot what actually the output comes..

```
div{float:left;margin:5px;}
```

Comment: This will (obviously) make all `div`'s float to the left, they may not want this, so @user3301042: Make sure to give your containerDiv a unique ID or Class name and reference that.

Comment: ofcourse this will make all div to left.. thats why i asked him to share a screenshot of code atleast so anyone can share their best idea..

Comment: Yeah I get it :) I was just letting the OP know incase they didn't know. :)